# Does Entity Framework Core cache result even after Context was disposed

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm comparing object materialization speed of different ORM libraries and ADO.NET.  The testing consist of querying 1, 10, 100 and 1000 results 11 times(I'll call 1 set) and repeat whole test again 10 times, so there are 10 set per querying testing.

The result of 1000 querying for no tracking entity is interesting, as expect the very first time query was executed is very slow, the following(2-11) is faster but the following set(2-10) is faster than ADO.NET!.

code for EF Core testing.  Keys is 2 dimensions array of 11 rows and 1000 columns.

```
    public override async Task TestFindByPK(int[,] keys)
    {
        // force load all assemblies before real executing
        using (var forceLoad = new AdventureWorks2012Context())
        {
            var ignore = await forceLoad.ErrorLog.ToListAsync();
        }

        for (var t = 0; t < 10; t++)
        {
            using (var context = new AdventureWorks2012Context())
            {
                context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
                var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

                for (var r = 0; r < keys.GetLength(0); r++)
                {
                    List<int> rows = GetRow(ref keys, r);
                    stopWatch.Restart();
                    var result = await context.SalesOrderHeader.Where(so => rows.Contains(so.SalesOrderId)).ToListAsync();
                    stopWatch.Stop();
                    await PrintTestFindByPKReport(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                }
            }

            Log.WriteLine($"Finish {t + 1} run{Environment.NewLine}");
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        }

        await Log.WriteLineAsync($"Complete on {DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()}{Environment.NewLine}");
    }
```

I guessed the result of query must be cached so that the following test set that use the same keys can retrieve result from cache otherwise EF Core must slower than ADO.NET.

**So, question 1, Does EF Core cache query result when specified no tracking result?**

Just in case that ADO.NET test code isn't efficient enough, this is code for ADO.NET test.

```
    public override async Task TestFindByPK(int[,] keys)
    {
        await PreloadAssemblies();
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader WHERE SalesOrderID IN " + CreateInSQLCommand(keys.GetLength(1));
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

        for (var t = 0; t < 10; t++)
        {
            try
            {
                conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                conn.Open();
                var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

                for (var r = 0; r < keys.GetLength(0); r++)
                {
                    var rows = GetRow(ref keys, r);
                    stopWatch.Restart();
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddRange(CreateParamForInClause(rows));
                    var reader = await sqlCmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
                    SalesOrderHeaderSQLserver salesOrderHeader = null;

                    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        salesOrderHeader = new SalesOrderHeaderSQLserver();
                        salesOrderHeader.SalesOrderId = reader.GetInt32(0);
                        salesOrderHeader.RevisionNumber = reader.GetByte(1);
                        salesOrderHeader.OrderDate = reader.GetDateTime(2);
                        salesOrderHeader.DueDate = reader.GetDateTime(3);
                        salesOrderHeader.ShipDate = await ConvertTo<DateTime?>(reader, 4);
                        salesOrderHeader.Status = reader.GetByte(5);
                        salesOrderHeader.OnlineOrderFlag = reader.GetBoolean(6);
                        salesOrderHeader.SalesOrderNumber = reader.GetString(7);
                        salesOrderHeader.PurchaseOrderNumber = await ConvertTo<string>(reader, 8);
                        salesOrderHeader.AccountNumber = await ConvertTo<string>(reader, 9);
                        salesOrderHeader.CustomerID = reader.GetInt32(10);
                        salesOrderHeader.SalesPersonID = await ConvertTo<int?>(reader, 11);
                        salesOrderHeader.TerritoryID = await ConvertTo<int?>(reader, 12);
                        salesOrderHeader.BillToAddressID = reader.GetInt32(13);
                        salesOrderHeader.ShipToAddressID = reader.GetInt32(14);
                        salesOrderHeader.ShipMethodID = reader.GetInt32(15);
                        salesOrderHeader.CreditCardID = await ConvertTo<int?>(reader, 16);
                        salesOrderHeader.CreditCardApprovalCode = await ConvertTo<string>(reader, 17);
                        salesOrderHeader.CurrencyRateID = await ConvertTo<int?>(reader, 18);
                        salesOrderHeader.SubTotal = reader.GetDecimal(19);
                        salesOrderHeader.TaxAmt = reader.GetDecimal(20);
                        salesOrderHeader.Freight = reader.GetDecimal(21);
                        salesOrderHeader.TotalDue = reader.GetDecimal(22);
                        salesOrderHeader.Comment = await ConvertTo<string>(reader, 23);
                        salesOrderHeader.Rowguid = reader.GetGuid(24);
                        salesOrderHeader.ModifiedDate = reader.GetDateTime(25);
                    }

                    stopWatch.Stop();
                    reader.Close();
                    await PrintTestFindByPKReport(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                }

            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception message : {ex.Message}");
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Dispose();
            }

            Log.WriteLine($"Finish {t + 1} run{Environment.NewLine}");
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        }

        await Log.WriteLineAsync($"Complete on {DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()}" + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

Other weird thing is that the first set is always slower than following set, I know that the very time query was executed it must be processed and translated to corresponding SQL command but it is cache but why 2-11 is slower than the following test set(it much faster than the very first time though).

**Does it because the IN clause with a set of values is considered to be different if set of values is difference?**